# Generate textView when length of edittext is not fixed

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have applied a textwatcher to my edittext. As the user enters the input, if it reaches a certain length I am automatically removing  the edittext and set that input to my text view.

```
if(s.toString().length()==4)
{
  pharmacyLoactionSetFalg=true;
  pharmacyLocation.setText(s.toString());
}
```

There is one more scenario where the user input may vary from 2 to 12. Under those conditions I cannot use the above code

Comment: "but i cant do the same if length could be anything!" means?

Comment: Length could be anything from 1 to 12

Comment: :your question is not clear.

Comment: Why have you used == in condition? I think you should use >=

Comment: this condition is for situations when user input needs to be just 4

Comment: Ok. So you are using different conditions to handle 2 to 12?

Comment: yes.but since i cant specify the no its nt working out

Answer (score 0):

You can use this check:

```
if(s.toString().length()>=2 && s.toString().length()<=12)
{
// your code here
}
```

this code will check weather the length is in between 2 and 12 or not.